# i want run service and broadcast receiver after the force close the application

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

How can I automatically restart my service and broadcast receiver after the application gets force close due to some error. Since I'm using inbuilt applications like calender and events. Some of the mobile doesnt support and getting force closed. How to handle those things and restart those service and broadcast receiver.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your receiver in the AndroidManifest. That way it will be called even when your app is not running: [R.styleable.AndroidManifestReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestReceive)

You could then check in the BroadcastReceiver whether the service is still running and restart it.

See for example the class SmSForwarder [here](https://github.com/flurischt/sms2HTTP/blob/master/src/ch/flurischt/sms2http/SmsForwarder.java). The broadcastreceiver does not need to run because it is registerend in the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/flurischt/sms2HTTP/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) (see line 29). Android will start the Broadcastreceiver as soon as the Intent "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" is sent.

Comment: can u give answer more detaily

Comment: in case, if my receiver is registered in class file,is it possible to get receiver even after application is closed??

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to define your receiver in xml. otherwise it wont be called if your application is not running.

Comment: I have the same problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816434/notifications-dont-come-through-when-the-app-is-closed) but can't get my head around your answer. My manifest looks the same. Would you mind giving more detail on how/why you need to check if "the service" (not sure what service) is running?