# Push notification does not happening when app is not running - android

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship for Push notification. Its works like a charm but just found that its did not sending push notification when application is not running.

How to handle this? I am sure its a common scenario and there will be a solution.

I checked many posts in stack overflow but most of them are for iOS. I want for Android

```
AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(this);

  UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
Logger.logLevel = Log.VERBOSE;


PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
PushManager.enablePush();
```

I have below code in Manifest Fie

```
   <!-- REQUIRED for Urban Airship GCM-->
    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.CoreReceiver" />

    <receiver android:name="com.urbanairship.push.GCMPushReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">        
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
          <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

          <!-- MODIFICATION REQUIRED - Use your package name as the category -->
          <category android:name="com.itest.guide.urbanairship" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushService" android:label="Push Notification Service"/>
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.push.PushWorkerService" android:label="Push Notification Worker Service"/>
    <service android:name="com.urbanairship.analytics.EventService" android:label="Event Service"/>

    <!-- This is required for persisting preferences related to push and location -->
    <provider android:name="com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider"
        android:authorities="com.itest.mauritiustourguide.urbanairship.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:multiprocess="true" />
    <!-- END OF REQUIRED ITEMS -->


    <!-- OPTIONAL, if you want to receive push, push opened and registration completed intents -->
    <!-- Replace the receiver below with your package and class name -->
    <receiver android:name="com.itest.guide.urbanairship.IntentReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason may be because of the Broadcast receiver in manifest file. Are you sure you put it? The broadcast receiver wakes the application up, and notifies when there is a push.

Comment: Nithinreddy, I added manifest content to this post. kindly comment

Comment: do I need to un-comment this?   <!--  OPTIONAL - This permission is only necessary if your app has multiple processes -->
    <!--  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" /> -->

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816434/notifications-dont-come-through-when-the-app-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the line the category in the BroadcastReceiver intent filter matches your app package

```
<category android:name="com.itest.guide.urbanairship" />
```